# How to calculate Young's modulus from a set of data?

Tags: statics, stress-strain, material-science, structural-beam

The set of data are ***force vs deflection***.

Is Young's modulus constant for a material?

If the beam is fixed by one fixed support and one vertical support
$E = \frac {F}{δ}\frac{3.5L^3}{384I}$

Comment: Youngs modulus is constant to a material as long as the material is within it's elastic limit

Comment: @slhulk can you explain how i could determine the Young's modulus of a beam from 7 sets of Force and Deflection? The first few force create much less deflection than the rest, and the force is only increasing by constant value

Comment: By deflection do u mean extension of the rod?

Comment: @slhulk one horizontal beam is put on top of two vertical support, a load is applied on the center of the beam, deflection is how much the beam stretch down from the origin

Comment: Is the initial length given?

Comment: What other data are given?. Also do they tell to ignore the change in the area of cross sec?

Comment: @slhulk yes, length , width, thickness are given, everything can be put into the formula, but since the first 2 sets create much less deflection, the calculated value is much different

Comment: If deflection is small, experimental errors can easily dominate. Plot the data you have and see whether the points lie on a straight line. If they don't, the degree of scatter tells you something about the error in your measurement. Can you plot the data in a way that you can get $E$ from the slope of the line through all the points?

Comment: Beam deflections and elastic modulus formulae: http://ruina.mae.cornell.edu/Courses/ME4735-2012/Rand4770Vibrations/BeamFormulas.pdf

Comment: @Floris thanks, i thought the deflection is supposed to be small for the first few force, i would not have this question if i knew

Comment: When you plot deflection as a function of the force, do the points appear to be on a straight line or not? Perhaps you can add that plot to the question. It would make things much clearer. You should not try to compute $E$ for each deflection; just for the set of points (assuming they lie on a straight line). What is the range of forces you use - and how does the deflection compare to the total length? That also matters...

Comment: @Floris it appears straight without the second point(only 7 points), It remains me of something about stress/strain curve, so i thought it is supposed to be this way. What do u mean by comparing to total length? the length is measured only once,  force range is 5N to 25N, length is 60cm, deflection ranges from 0.0xx to 30

Comment: @floris i conducted 2 different settings with different length and supports, how does length affect young's modulus?

Comment: I meant "is the deflection small compared to the length"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a set of data to determine a particular value, it is often a good idea to find a way to plot the data so the number you want is either the slope, or the intercept, of a straight line through the data. Here is a simple example I concocted. Imagine the force/deflection measurement you want to make has a small systematic error as well as a little bit of noise on it. I created a dataset where the relationship between force and deflection is given by

```
deflection = force * 0.1 + 0.2 * rand() + 0.1
```

In other words - there is a bit of noise, and a small offset (systematic error). The resulting datapoints are:

```
force    deflection   E
  1        0.34      2.93
  2        0.31      6.52
  4        0.61      6.54
  8        0.94      8.52
 16        1.76      9.10
 32        3.45      9.29
 64        6.50      9.84
```

But if you draw a straight line through the data, the slope you get is 0.099  - very close to the "true" value of 0.1; it also shows an intercept of 0.2 - as you would expect from the systematic error I introduced with my equation (0.1 fixed offset, and 0.1 due to the random factor).

[image]

This is of course just a simple example - but I hope it illustrates the principle. A straight line plot helps you see the relationship more clearly than calculation of the same value from individual points - the small systematic error really makes a mess of those first few points in this example. And with a bit more effort the plot helps you estimate the size of the error as well.

Note - to get Young's modulus from your data, you need to do a bit of math after determining the slope of the straight line through your data - but I'm sure you can figure that piece out.